# How do you remote-debug a 32-bit native app running on Win7/64 from VS 2008, also running on Win7/64?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, 32bit-64bit, remote-debugging

My workstation is Windows 7 64-bit.  I am trying to remote-debug an x86 (32-bit) application running on a Windows 7 64-bit VM.  I have installed rdbgsetup_x64.exe on the VM, which installs both 32 and 64 bit versions of msvsmon.exe into C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger.

If I run the 64-bit version of msvsmon.exe on the VM, I can attach to the 32-bit application from my workstation, but no symbols are loaded and no breakpoints are hit.

If I run the 64-bit version of msvsmon.exe on the VM and attempt to launch the 32-bit application remotely (via Debug->Start New Instance), it fails, saying, "Unable to start program.  The 64-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot debug 32-bit processes or 32-bit dumps.  Please use the 32-bit version instead."

But if I run the 32-bit version of msvsmon.exe on the VM, I get the following error when I attempt to attach to any process running on the VM from my workstation: "Unable to attach to the process.  An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80004002).  If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Conrol Panel."  I get the same error if I try to launch the 32-bit application remotely from my workstation (using Debug->Start New Instance).

My question is how do I remote-debug a 32-bit application running on Win7/64 from a workstation running Win7/64?

Thanks!

Comment: Which VM software are you using? If it's VMware, it comes with a Visual Studio add-in (option during VMware installation) which somewhat automates all of this. I say 'somewhat' because it can still be quite tricky to get working. (Firewalls and VM-networking stuff get in the way and the VS remote debugger isn't very helpful when things don't work, so you have to get all the stars aligned perfectly. :( But I have used it to debug both 32-bit and 64-bit processes within a 64-bit VM.)

Comment: Why are you using a VM?  Just set the Platform Target on the EXE project to x86, no VM necessary.

Comment: @Leo: I'm using VMWare Workstation 7.1.  I have no problems attaching to and debugging 64-bit apps on the VM.  It's when I try to debug 32-bit apps on the same VM that I run into trouble.  I read somewhere that I need to run the 32-bit version of msvsmon to make this work, but when I do that I get the error I quoted above ("...that usually indicates a corrupt installation...").

Comment: @Hans: I use a VM because my product installs lots of things I don't want on my workstation in development form - drivers, shell extensions, service, hook injection, etc.  VMs are a necessity in our shop.

Answer (score 0):

The 32bit msvsmon should work. If it doesn't, it could be that some dlls are not same version on the developer machine and on the remote test machine. Try updating both to the latest service pack. A similar issue is described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/fd2feec2-0c75-4e40-85fb-302c85c502be)

Besides, if your Visual Studio does not support this scenario, you can always use WinDbg (suggesting as the question title does not explicitly says 'with Visual Studio'). It supports all kinds of remote debugging scenarios. I often debug similar scenarios with WinDBG. There are lots of tutorials on WinDbg online, but Advanced Windows Debugging book is certainly the best.

Comment: hi is it possible to debug in the same scenario except visual studio is installed on a 32 bit machine or host machine is 32 bit and remote machine is 64 bit